# passing Data from TableView after searchResult

Tags: objective-c, search, nsstring, tableview, searchbar

(Using X-Code 4.6)

I have a problem with my TableView:

I have like a 100 Names in there.

Click on one and it goes to the detailView with buttons and Labels. 
Everything works fine until i use the Searchbar.

Of course after in the search Results the name that was at row 85 is ow at row 1 and it passes the data from row 1.

**Is it possible to somehow permanently attach all data (strings) from row 85 together?**

I have 4 Strings: Name, CellPhoneNumber, BuisNumber and Mail.

Name goes to a label and the rest are variables to buttons.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.nameIdentity = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.nameIdentity = [nameData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.cellNumberIdentity = [cellNumberData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.buisNumberIdentity = [buisNumberData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.mailIdentity = [mailData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

} }
}
```

I do get the correct Name to the label, but how to get the rest.

Comment: How do you set up the data source for the search results table view?

Comment: I`m using an NSArray *nameData.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right it will be better to create class e.g. Person. it will have 4 parameters name, mail, cellNumber, businessNumber.
Then You will need 2 arrays fullPersonData and currentSearchPersonData. 
So that next time when you will doing search you will need:
1)to search in fullPerson array occurrences of search word and copy them to currentSearchData
2)reload table with currentSearchData array (you can use bool flag like isSearch to trig tableView delegates to take data from needed array)

After that there is no need to think on what row was cell before search just toke objectAtIndex from neded array and pass it to detailView. and detailView will fill itself))

Comment: Do you mean an Array that contains all the Data of the person?
How do i creat a Array that hold a name, 2 phoneNumbers and an E-Mail Adress that i can access indivualy. 

I propably misunderstood. Can you explain a little more specifically?

Comment: Look for this link. It's online obj c tutorial. You will find there how to create a class http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html. When you will create a Class Person *currentPerson = [Person new]; you will be able to do something like this: person.number = 1234; person.name = @"tom" ... and also get this parameters like int number = person.number